# Visual Studio 2019 Python re-installation

Tags: python, visual-studio-2019

Unable to reinstall Python 3.7.8 files/folders in Visual Studio 2019

Hi all,

Can anyone tell me how I can re-install Python 3.7.8 into the VS shared directory? We have an instance where the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64 folder was somehow deleted yet upon re-installing/repairing VS 2019, the folders are never re-created. Have also tried completely uninstalling VS 2019 using installcleanup.exe yet re-installing still doesn't recreate the files.

Note this is an off-line installation via layout. The Python source setup files are present in the layout.

Thanks,

Pooty